# % symbols in strings passed from javascript to controllers in grails in strings turning them null

Tags: javascript, string, grails

So, Ive done some digging and I cant find a reason for this, I've got some javascript for a simple search like so: -

```
function search(searchString, domain, destinationIdentifier) {

    alert(searchString)
    var uri = formUriWithDefaults([domain, "/search"], {searchString : searchString})

}
```

This looks like this because Im using the same search for multiple different pages.  Ive then got a simple controller like so: -

```
def search(String searchString) {

    println("received search " + searchString)

    ....do other stuff to blow your mind....
}
```

If I enter "elephant" or "hyperloop" or "random" etc and search then these are output as I'd expect in the controller with a line reading "received search elephant" etc.  But the moment I try and make it "hyper%" etc it then just prints out 'received search null' instead...  Does anyone know why adding a % into my search string makes it go blam?

Thanks for any help, much appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling your controller? Are you using `GET` or `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `encodeAsRaw()` **but**, this may open up a security hole in you application for cross-site scripting.  It would look something like this:

```
{searchString : searchString.encodeAsRaw()})
```

A better option might be to change the wildcard identifier to be '*' and then do a replace in the controller on only that char.

Something like this:

```
searchString = searchString.replace("*","%")
```